# Does the person breaking get the choice of solids or stripes if he makes any ball in?

Tags: rules, pool

When playing 8-ball, if the breaking player hits any ball on the break, does the shooting player have a verbal choice of stripes or solids? Or does he still have to call a shot in before he can?

If the rule is that he has to call his shot to get either stripes or solids, then what happens if on the break he hits a solid in, but calls a shot for stripes and misses it?

Answer (score 1):

> does the shooting player have a verbal choice of stripes or solids?

No one ever has verbal choice.  Whenever the table is open (as is always true after a break), then the group is chosen by successfully pocketing a called shot.  The group containing the made shot is then that player's.  [WPA Rules](https://wpapool.com/rules-of-play/), rule 3.4.

> what happens if on the break he hits a solid in, but calls a shot for stripes and misses it?

The table is open after the break (even if balls are pocketed) (Rule 3.3(c)).  By missing the called shot, the table remains open for the opponent.